# Uploading directories with sftp?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I'm having some trouble uploading directories(which contain other directories a few levels deep) by sftp. I realize I could work around this by gzipping, but I don't see why that's necessary.

Anyway, I try

```
sftp> put bin/
Uploading bin/ to /home/earlz/blah/bin
bin/ is not a regular file
sftp> put -r bin/
Uploading bin/ to /home/earlz/blah/bin
Couldn't canonicalise: No such file or directory
Unable to canonicalise path "/home/earlz/blah/bin"
```

I think the last error message is completely stupid. So the directory doesn't exist? Why not create the directory?

Is there anyway around this issue with sftp, or should I just use scp?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**CORRECTED**: I initially claimed wrongly that OpenSSH did not support `put -r`.  It does, but it does it in a very strange way.  It seems to expect the destination directory to already exist, with the same name as the source directory.

```
sftp> put -r source
 Uploading source/ to /home/myself/source
 Couldn't canonicalize: No such file or directory
 etc.
sftp> mkdir source
sftp> put -r source
 Uploading source/ to /home/myself/source
 Entering source/
 source/file1
 source/file2
```

What's especially strange is that this even applies if you give a different name for the destination:

```
sftp> put -r source dest
 Uploading source/ to /home/myself/dest
 Couldn't canonicalize: ...
sftp> mkdir dest
sftp> put -r source dest
 Uploading source/ to /home/myself/dest/source
 Couldn't canonicalize: ...
sftp> mkdir dest/source
sftp> put -r source dest
 Uploading source/ to /home/myself/dest/source
 Entering source/
 source/file1
 source/file2
```

For a better-implemented recursive `put`, you could use the PuTTY `psftp` command line tool instead.  It's in the `putty-tools` package under Debian (and most likely Ubuntu).

Alternately, Filezilla will do what you want, if you want to use a GUI.

Comment: FYI: `sftp` allows `put -r` from [OpenSSH 5.4](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.4)

Comment: Thanks -- I've corrected my answer.  It's about time, huh? ;-P

Comment: I see put -r doesn't expect the source directory as the same name as the destination.

Answer (score 161):

I don't know why sftp does this but you can only recursive copy if the destination directory already exists. So do this...

```
sftp> mkdir bin
sftp> put -r bin
```

Comment: `-r` needs [OpenSSH 5.4](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.4) or higher

Answer (score 21):

You might be interested in using `rsync` instead. The command for that would be

```
 rsync --delete --rsh=ssh -av bin/ remote-ip-or-fqdn:/home/earlz/blah/bin/
```

This will copy everything in `bin/` and place it in on the remote server in `/home/earlz/blah/bin/`. As an added benefit, it will first check to see if the file on the remote side hasn't changed, and if it hasn't, it won't re-send it. Additionally, you can add a -z option and it will compress it for you.

Comment: Awsome! So simple!

Comment: Please note that `sftp` is a command **and a protocol**.  `rsync` does not support the `sftp`-protocol.

Answer (score 18):

`lcd`: your local folder (with subfolders)

`cd`: your remote folder

`put -r .`

Comment: actually, I think this is the most correct answer... for the purpose of putting my whole folder there

Comment: sftp complained when I cd'd into the local parent folder and tried to put the directory by name. But `cd`'ing into the directory I wanted to upload did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

May I suggest a somewhat complicated answer, without zipping, but including tar?

Here we go:

```
tar -cf - ./bin | ssh target.org " ( cd /home/earlz/blah ; tar -xf - ) "
```

This will pack the directory ./bin with tar (-cf:=create file), filename - (none, stdout) and pipe it through the ssh-command to target.org (which might as well be an IP) where the command in quotes is performed, which is: 
cd to blah, and tar -xf (extract file) - none, no name, just stdin.

It's as if you pack a package at home, bring it to the post, then drive to work, where you expect the package and open it.

Maybe there is a much more elegant solution which just uses sftp.

Comment: A piped `tar` is a very good solution, however this needs `ssh` login support (`sftp` is a different protocol on top of `ssh`).  `tar`, unlike others, **by default**, runs recursively, transfers all special files (FIFO, block/character devices etc.), tries to translate the UID/GID mapping from the source to the target system and has a traditional short commandline.  (One exception though: "Unix domain sockets" are not transferred.  But who needs those?)

Comment: I use this method when I need compression between nodes also you can use the `pv` tool to watch speed in long transfers

Answer (score 2):

You can use [yafc](http://yafc.sourceforge.net/) (Yet anoter FTP/SFTP client). The `-r` option works there very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **rsync**, which  is a very powerful alternative for scp and sftp, especially when updating the copies from machine A to machine B, as it doesn't copy the files that haven't been altered; it's also able to remove files from machine B that have been deleted from machine A (only when it's told to of course).

for example :

```
rsync -zrp /home/a/ user@remote.host.com:/home/b/
```

The -r option is for recursively copying files, -z enables compression during the transfer, and -p preserves the file permissions (file creation, edit, etc.) when copying, which is something that scp doesn't do AFAIK. Many more options are possible; as usual, read the man pages.
[Original answer by Karolos](https://superuser.com/questions/387477/sftp-upload-all-files-directories-and-sub-directories-contained-in-a-folder)

Comment: This is a dupe of Shawn J. Goff's answer from Feb 7 '11 at 19:24. Using rsync like this requires SSH access; it doesn't work with an account that only has SFTP access.

Answer (score 1):

Login to the remote server with ssh, use sftp to connect back to your box, then use the `get -r` command to transfer directories to the remote server.
The get command allows you to transfer directories recursively without having the directory already created.

```
ssh remote ip
sftp local ip 
get -r whichever-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

SFTP case:

I needed to copy that structure on my ftp:

```
mainfolder --- folder --- subfolder
                  |           |
              file1.txt   file2.txt
```

That solved my problem:

```
cd ./mainfolder
mkdir folder
put -r /from/source/folder/* /mainfolder/folder/
cd ./folder
mkdir subfolder
put -r /from/source/folder/subfolder/* /mainfolder/folder/subfolder/
```

Answer (score 0):

I just learned from the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot#Installation) that it is possible to mount the sftp-share using sshfs. I'm running an [sftp-server with chroot and jail](https://www.linuxtechi.com/configure-chroot-sftp-in-linux/) and sshfs works very well.

1. Mount: `sshfs <sftpuser>@<server>:<read/writable/directory> <your/local/mount/directory>`
2. Unmount: `fusermount -u <your/local/mount/directory>`

Answer (score 0):

Given the following local structure (inspired by by [@nikita-malovichko](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325738/448181)):

```
~ --- mainfolder --- folder --- subfolder
                        |           |
                    file1.txt   file2.txt
```

I use this one-liner to upload a whole local directory mainfolder:

```
# Powershell:
Write-Output 'put mainfolder' | sftp -r -i "~/.ssh/ssh.pem" ubuntu@my-url.com:~/my-remote-target
```

```bsh
Bash
echo 'put mainfolder' | sftp -r -i "~/.ssh/ssh.pem" ubuntu@my-url.com:~/my-remote-target
```

If you want to upload everything in the directory `mainfolder` but unpack it (so to speak) use `put mainfolder/*` or as the whole command:

```
# Powershell:
Write-Output 'put mainfolder/*' | sftp -r -i "~/.ssh/ssh.pem" ubuntu@my-url.com:~/my-remote-target
```

```bsh
Bash
echo 'put mainfolder/*' | sftp -r -i "~/.ssh/ssh.pem" ubuntu@my-url.com:~/my-remote-target
```